# Current location not showing in iOS simulator using annotation to point specific location in MKMapView

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to show the user location in MKMapView when I run this app. Set all the required permission in .plist, though not getting "blue dot" on mapView. Hope will help some one`enter code here`. In advance thank you.

Here is code:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){

  mapView.showUserlocation = true
  mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        mapView.register(MKPinAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)
      
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
}
```

// Written to show an Annotation in map:

```
 let annotation1 = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        annotation1.title = "Bangalore"
        annotation1.subtitle = "Gandhi hills"
        self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation1)
        self.mapView.delegate = self
```

//MKMapViewdelegate and CLLocationManagerDelegate methods()

```
extension CarServiceVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        if #available(ios 14.0,*){
            switch manager.authorizationStatus{
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Not determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            case .denied:
                print("Denied")
            case .authorizedAlways:
                print("Authorized Always")
            case .authorizedWhenInUse:
                print("Authorized when in use")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown status")
            }
        }
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        switch status{
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not determined")
        case .restricted:
            print("Restricted")
        case .denied:
            print("Denied")
        case .authorizedAlways:
            print("Authorized Always")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Authorized when in use")
        @unknown default:
            print("Unknown status")
        }
    }
}
extension CarService1: MKMapViewDelegate{
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not setting `MKMapView`'s `showsUserLocation` to true.

Comment: I set userLocation through storybord@ElTomato.